# GWT - how to precisely set rendered width of TextArea in pixels?

Tags: gwt, textbox, width, pixel

I need to render a `TextArea` in an exact pixel width for the special purposes of my GUI.

When I set its width to "250px", it comes out as 256px.

Is there a way to override this behavior so I can render it as 250px exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `setWidth()`, you're effectively setting the element's *content* width.

To get the *offset* width use [`UIObject#getOffsetWidth()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getOffsetWidth%28%29). This will return the width including padding and border (but not margins).

#### References on W3C

- [Computing widths and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins)
- [The box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)